# VSCode TFVC - Please ensure an English version is properly configured

Tags: visual-studio-code, tfvc

I installed TFVC in VSCode and am seeing an error message.

```
(team) It appears you have configured a non-English version of the TF executable. Please ensure an English version is properly configured.
```

I added the line below in Settings.

```
"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\TF.exe"
```

I renamed the "de" folder where "TF.exe" is (as per some solutions I found on the Internet).But it also did not work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, trying to use the TF.exe (installation of Visual Studio 2015). What solved my case was:

1) Installed the [Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#how-can-i-acquire-tfexe-do-i-need-a-version-of-visual-studio) (I have chosen languages pack Portuguese and English during the installation)

2) Renamed my language folder located in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"`, from `"pt-BR"` to `"_pt-BR"`. As my SO is in portuguese, that is why I renamed pt-BR. Maybe not choosing Portuguese in step 1 would solve all the problem, but I didn't try that.

3) Configure the new TF.exe in VS Code, my path was `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"`

Reopened the VS Code. The error was not showed anymore.

Comment: Worked well! Thank you